# trying to convert a letter to uppercase using .toUpperCase()... doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to convert a character in an array to uppercase using .toUpperCase(), but it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure my logic is correct, so not sure why it's not working?

```js
var test = "hello*3";


function LetterChanges(str) {
  //var testArr = str.split("");
  var tempArr = [];

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) >= 97 && str.charCodeAt(i) <= 122) {

      tempArr.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
      tempArr[i] = tempArr[i] + 1;
      tempArr[i] = String.fromCharCode(tempArr[i]);

      if (tempArr[i] == "p" || tempArr[i] == "i") {
        tempArr[i].toUpperCase();
        console.log(tempArr[i]); //this will display "i" and "p".. why?
      }

    } else {
      tempArr[i] = str[i];
    }


  }
  console.log(tempArr); //this display [ 'i', 'f', 'm', 'm', 'p', '*', '3' ]

  str = tempArr.join("");
  return str;

}
```

So it seems that when I'm comparing "p" and "i" it was able to detect it, but it doesn't convert it to uppercase.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> console.log(tempArr[i]); //this will display "i" and "p".. why?

because you were not storing the converted value back to the variable

make it

```
tempArr[i] = tempArr[i].toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct, however I slightly modified the code you wrote, 
as things can be achieved without using arrays.

```
var test = "hello*3";
LetterChanges(test)

function LetterChanges(str) {
var newStr = ""
 for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
 var ch = str[i];
 if(ch >='A' && ch<='z'){
    ch =  String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
   if(ch == 'p' || ch == 'i')
   ch = ch.toUpperCase();
   }
   newStr += ch;
 }

console.log(newStr);
return newStr;
}
```

Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fzme18q0/2/